How to compile C code for both native (x86_64-linux) and ARM using a .bb file
I have my C code under libProject. And this code is compiled for ARM now.
I want to compile the same code for native (x86_64-linux) machine. This is failing at do_fetch()
Using bitbake file to build the code.
I have add below line in my libProject.bb to extend the build for native machine too.
BBCLASSEXTEND = "native"

My code is present in the folder named libProject.
When compiled using bitbake libProject , the libProject builds fine (coz it is for ARM).
But, when i run bitbake libProject-native , the build fails with below error.
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_fetch
| tar: libProject-native: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
| tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
| WARNING: exit code 2 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_fetch (log file is located at /neptune/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/libProject-native/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.10986)


By using the BBCLASSEXTEND = "native" line here you are telling bitbake that for this recipe libProject, it should also build this recipe for the native machine using :class-native and :class-target overrides for seperate functionality as per the user manual. You are not giving bitbake an entirely new recipe hence why trying to run bitbake with the -native doesn't work, it is looking for a file that just doesn't exist since the functionality for both native and target are in the one recipe.
If you want to run bitbake for only the native you could make your own custom libProject-native.bb, modify it how you want, then run it with the bitbake command to make sure it works.

Thank you Will! for the response. Similiar to your suggession, i had already tried having separate bb file as libProject-native.bb. This bb file will expect the source code name to be libProject-native. If not, build will again fail at do_fetch(). So I tried having a copy of the source code and that works. But it will need to have copy of source code twice. (one for ARM one for native). My intention is to have only one source code.
